# Replace column headers - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to replace column headers in a pandas df. Particularly, I want to change the columns ending in `_Item`. At the moment the start of those column headers begins with whatever string is in `Group_A` or `Group_B`. But these strings will change with each new dataset. So I'm hoping to replace the appropriate string values with `Group A` or `Group B`.

At the moment, I'm manually replacing the column headers but this doesn't work if the columns aren't ordered.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Group_A' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red'],                                   
    'Group_B' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue'],       
    'Blue_Item' : ['2','4','6','8','10','12',],                              
    'Red_Item' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6',],                                                          
    })

df.columns = [*df.columns[:-2], 'Group_A_Item','Group_B_Item']
```

intended output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Group_A' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red'],                                   
    'Group_B' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue'],       
    'Group_B_Item' : ['2','4','6','8','10','12',],                              
    'Group_A_Item' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6',],                                                          
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `rename` method. To use it, provide a `dict` with key being the current name and associated key being the name you want in replacement. All columns name that does not appear in the dict is left unchanged. This gives the following code in your case :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Group_A' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red'],                                   
    'Group_B' : ['Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue'],       
    'Blue_Item' : ['2','4','6','8','10','12',],                              
    'Red_Item' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6',],                                                          
    })

df = df.rename(columns={'Blue_Item': 'Group_B_Item', 'Red_Item': 'Group_A_Item'})
```

This way, renaming does not depends on column order.

Find more with the [pandas' rename documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

As you specifically want to dynamically rename your columns (you said you want to replace appropriate strings with `Group_A` or `Group_B`), you can still write a method to dynamiccaly build the dictionnary to provide to the rename method.